# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable em Python

Tags: python

Tenho um exercício que consiste em definir uma classe `Triangulo` e um método `retangulo()`, que retornará `True` se o objeto for um triângulo retângulo.

Eu sempre gostei de usar listas para resolver meus problemas, então escrevi o seguinte código:

```
def retangulo(self):

    lados = [self.a, self.b, self.c].sort()

    if (lados[0] ** 2) + (lados[1] ** 2) == (lados[2] ** 2):
        return True

    return False
```

No entanto, ao fazer isso recebo o erro do título do tópico. Eu também tentei digitar `tri1.b ** 2 + tri1.c ** 2 = tri1.a ** 2` no IDLE (interpretador), mas aí sou avisado de que `SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator`.

O que eu estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo a documentação, o [método `sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) ordena a lista *in-place* (ou seja, modifica a própria lista) e também é dito que "*it does not return the sorted sequence*" (não retorna a lista ordenada).

Mais ainda, a [documentação também diz](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#built-in-types) que:

> *The methods that add, subtract, or rearrange their members in place, and don’t return a specific item, never return the collection instance itself but `None`.*

Ou seja, métodos como `sort`, que alteram o conteúdo *in place* e não retornam a própria lista, retornam `None`.

Então no seu caso a variável `lados` estava com o valor `None`, e ao tentar obter um elemento da mesma (com `lados[0]`), dá o erro de *NoneType object is not subscriptable*.

Uma forma de resolver é primeiro criar a lista e depois ordená-la:

```
lados = [self.a, self.b, self.c]
lados.sort()
# etc...
```

Ou então usar [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), que retorna a lista ordenada:

```
lados = sorted([self.a, self.b, self.c])
# etc...
```

Outra forma é, em vez de criar a lista `lados`, usar a atribuição múltipla:

```
def retangulo(self):
    a, b, c = sorted([self.a, self.b, self.c])

    return a ** 2 + b ** 2 == c ** 2
```

Desta forma, as variáveis `a`, `b` e `c` receberão respectivamente o primeiro, segundo e terceiro elementos da lista ordenada que `sorted` retorna (vale lembrar que elas são locais à função e não se confundem com `self.a`, `self.b` e `self.c`). E no cálculo os parênteses são desnecessários, já que [a exponenciação tem precedência maior que a soma](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Repare também que eu posso retornar diretamente o resultado da comparação, já que o resultado de uma comparação com `==` é um *booleano* (ou seja, é `True` ou `False`). De forma geral, qualquer expressão do tipo:

```
if condicao:
    return True
return False
```

Pode ser resumida para:

```
return condicao
```

Como `condicao` no seu caso é um *booleano*, você pode retorná-la diretamente. Isso só faria diferença se `condicao` não fosse booleano, já que em Python [qualquer objeto pode ser usado em um contexto *booleano*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) (e aí seria retornado o próprio objeto em vez de `True` ou `False`), mas como é o resultado de uma comparação, você pode retorná-lo diretamente.

---

Sobre o erro que você obteve no terminal, creio que seja erro de digitação, pois o que você digitou é:

```
tri1.b ** 2 + tri1.c ** 2 = tri1.a ** 2
```

Sendo que você deveria usar `==` em vez de `=`. Apenas um sinal de igual é o operador de atribuição, que não faz sentido no contexto acima. Trocando para `==`, funcionaria sem problemas.